# Extending a model to a given compactification of its generic fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, compactifications

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring and $K$ its field of fraction. Let $X$ be a proper $K$-variety, $U$ a dense open and consider an $R$-model $\mathcal{U}$ of $U$.
**Can we embed $\mathcal{U}$ in a proper $R$-model of $X$?**

Nagata's embedding theorem ensures the existence of a compactification for $\mathcal{U}$, but I don't see any way to force its generic fiber to be $X$.

Comment: It is possible to apply Nagata's theorem to the $R$-scheme obtained by glueing $\mathcal{U}$ and $X$ along $U$.

Comment: @OlivierBenoist: right, but you just have to check that this $R$-scheme is separated, e.g. by the valuative criterion.

Comment: Oh, that's great! Thanks you two for the tips!